# Reverse value (categorical) order of colorbar

Tags: python, pandas, colorbar

I have a dataframe where energylabel is a categorical variable.

```
>>> df
    costs  EP2
0     0.0  260
1  5866.0  230
2  5755.0   32
3   722.0  -42
4  6588.0  103
>>> bins_energylabel = [-np.inf, 0, 50, 75, 105, 160, 190, 250, 290, 335, 380, np.inf]
>>> labs_energylabel = ['A++++', 'A+++', 'A++', 'A+', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
>>> df['energylabel'] = pd.cut(df['EP2'], bins=bins_energylabel, labels=labs_energylabel)
>>> df
    costs  EP2 energylabel
0     0.0  260           D
1  5866.0  230           C
2  5755.0   32        A+++
3   722.0  -42       A++++
4  6588.0  103          A+
```

I want to plot the costs versus EP2 and coloring the energylabels with their corresponding energylabel.

```
ax1 = df.plot.scatter(x='costs', y='EP2', c='energylabel', colormap='Set3', sharex=False)
```

Looks something like this:

[image]

Now I want to reverse the order of the colormap values: instead of `G` on top, I want `A++++` etc..
My original dataframe is longer and contains more labels, the categories are ordered like so (this is done by using `pd.cut()` on column `EP2`).

```
Categories (11, object): ['A++++' < 'A+++' < 'A++' < 'A+' ... 'D' < 'E' < 'F' < 'G']
```

I think by reversing the order it can solve my problem. But is it also possible to do this directly from the plotting code above?

Comment: can you provide code to set up a minimal dataframe with the categorical?

Comment: code is added at the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can reverse the colormap by adding an `_r` suffix and invert the colorbar Y-axis with [`invert_yaxis`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.invert_yaxis.html):

```
ax = df.plot.scatter(x='costs', y='EP2', c='energylabel',
                     colormap='Set3_r',  # '_r' suffix to invert the cmap colors
                     sharex=False)
cbar = ax.figure.axes[-1]
cbar.invert_yaxis()
```

output:

[image: matplotlib inverted colorbar and cmap]

*NB. inverting the colors is optional, if you don't, you will get:*

[image: matplotlib inverted colorbar]